# can global variables be incremented in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, increment

```
var t = 0;
function addDiv()
{
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    t++;
    div.setAttribute("id", "box" + t);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    AddStyle();
}

var h = 0;
var p = 1;    
function doMove()
{
    var okj = document.getElementById("box" + p);

    if (p <= t) {
        p++; 
    }
    var g = setInterval(function () {
        var go = parseInt(okj.style.left, 0) + 1 + "px";
        okj.style.left = go;
    }, 1000 / 60);
}
```

My question is that after the p increments that is p++ will my `var p = 1` be incremented everytime I call `doMove`? Please help me regarding this matter.

Comment: can't you just do a alert(p) to see if it really increments or not? - I guess it won't, since t is not a global so p is never <= t

Comment: Please see this very fine question and answer: [JavaScript Variable Scope][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Comment: @Borgtex sorry i forgot to mention there is a variable called t=0 and what i am not getting is javascript is interpreted based how can p go backwards and gets each time increemented

Comment: @MarkWalters sorry i forgot to mention there is a variable called t=0 at top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition global variables have global scope, so you can increment them or re-assign them within a function and that will work, how fantastic is that!

Although as Borgtex has pointed out your `if` statement won't work

```
if (p <= t) {
   p++; 
}
```

You have declared the variable `t` in another function so your `doMove()` function does not have access to it, therefore this statement will always return `false`; If you make `t` a global variable or pass it into your `doMove()` function as a parameter then this will work.

```
var p = 1; // this variable is global

function varTest(){
   p++ //This will work because p is global so this function has access to it.
   var t = 0;
}

function anotherTest(){
   if(p<t){   //This will return false - t is not in scope as it was defined in another function
      alert("supercalifragilisticexpihalitoscious"); 
   }
}
```

Comment: @Connor My bad, it was a long time ago when I last saw it and my memory of the film is a bit skewed. Thank you for the correction, I shall never make this mistake again.